# Group Policy Object with Max Password Will Not Take Affect

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

We are having an odd issue with out AD. We have changed the password policy to be as follows:

```
Enforce password history 5 passwords remembered
Maximum password age
120 days  Minimum password age 1 day
Minimum password length 8 characters
```

This policy has been in affect since before January of this year. Our users are still having to change their password every 42 days, though. I understand that the policy doesn't take effect until your password has been changed. Our users have changed their passwords a handful of times since the change.

On the server when I run *net accounts* I see the following:

```
Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       Never
Minimum password age (days):                          1
Maximum password age (days):                          120
Minimum password length:                              8
Length of password history maintained:                5
Lockout threshold:                                    15
Lockout duration (minutes):                           5
Lockout observation window (minutes):                 5
Computer role:                                        PRIMARY
```

Great! 120 days for Maximum Password! Now I check on a specific user with *net user*

```
User name                    Removed
Full Name                    Removed
Comment
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            5/5/2015 2:54:35 PM
Password expires             9/2/2015 2:54:35 PM
Password changeable          5/6/2015 2:54:35 PM
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   4/9/2015 4:13:10 PM

Logon hours allowed          All
```

Ok, perfect! 9/2 is 120 days after 5/5! This is typical, however. Before this user changed their password on 5/5 it was showing a date beyond 5/5 (when their password *actually* expired.

Today I found a [new-to-me way to check a users password expiration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2010/02/26/find-out-when-your-password-expires.aspx). So I check this same user with this tool that uses *Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy* to determine MaxPasswordAge (I was able to confirm it was going down the *$accountFGPP -ne $null* route by manually running *Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy*. The function spits this out:

```
Password of account: SameUserAsBefore expires on: 06/16/2015 14:54:35
```

Wait, what? *net user* had said the password didn't expire until 9/2! When I ran *Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy* on this user I found the root of the issue:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy (Get-ADUser SameUserAsBefore -properties PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordLastSet)

AppliesTo                   : {CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=REMOVED,DC=LOCAL}
ComplexityEnabled           : False
DistinguishedName           : CN=Default-#####,CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=REMOVED,DC=LOCAL
LockoutDuration             : 00:30:00
LockoutObservationWindow    : 00:30:00
LockoutThreshold            : 10
MaxPasswordAge              : 42.00:00:00
MinPasswordAge              : 1.00:00:00
MinPasswordLength           : 7
Name                        : Default-#####
ObjectClass                 : msDS-PasswordSettings
ObjectGUID                  : GUIDRemoved
PasswordHistoryCount        : 3
Precedence                  : 1
ReversibleEncryptionEnabled : False
```

And here I am, dumbfounded as to why it's 42 days despite the Group Policy I have set which is enforced and linked at the domain level. It's set to apply to Authenticated Users. I have tried deleting this and remaking it in case the policy had become corrupt in some way.

Does anyone have any idea why the group policy isn't actually taking affect?

Comment: I was reading a new article about how to see which policies are being applied to a computer/user account using rsop.msc. I ran this on my computer as myself and it ran with no issues. The policy was showing as it was set in Group Policy Management. However, when I ran it as one of our users it failed to display the Computer Configuration entirely due to the fact that our users are not administrators of the system. I'm not sure if this is a limitation of rsop.msc or if this might be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has finally been solved! A whole new world of Windows Server has been revealed to me.

From Mec Beau and edited by Excellll:

> By creating GPO on OU, This will not work for what you're trying to do. GPOs pertaining to Password policies can only be set at the domain level. However, In order to apply a policy to a subset of domain users then you need to use Fine-Grained password policies.
>
> These can be applied at the group level, so you need to ensure all the users you wish to affect with this new policy are a member of the appropriate group.
>
> To do this on a Windows 2012 domain, do the following from a DC .
>
> 1. From the Start Screen type DSAC.EXE to start the Directory Service Administrative Center.
> 2. Navigate to the System\Password Settings Container
> 3. Right Click and select New or use New under the Tasks menu.
> 4. Choose Password Settings
> 5. Create a New Password policy either for a User or a group.
> 6. Set its Precedence in case if u have multiple policies created, so lower the number higher the priority.
>
> It's fairly self-explanatory from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and the reason was that there was a Block Inheritance al Domain Controller OU level.

If there is an inheritance block there, the password settings will not apply.

You can check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/269236/changes-are-not-applied-when-you-change-the-password-policy) to read the full MS Article.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/269236/changes-are-not-applied-when-you-change-the-password-policy